# How to use Image Zooming features in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am developing a web application in Angular 5 and I want to use Image zooming features something like explained in the below link

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp

The link explains very nicely some image zooming features but it uses java script defined in  tag.

My query is how can I use such features in Angular 5 or Angular 6

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: You can use this in any js framework, since it's plain js. But, it would be better to convert it to ES6 and typescript. You should make a reusable component where all the zooming logic is written.

Comment: So in order to use Js framework  I need to load those .js files in angular and then use the features.Is that what you mean to say ?

Comment: You need to put the code inside of an angular component. Then you could make for example image-url as an input. And that would make the component reusable.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoom-image)

HTML:

```
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container" (mouseenter)="imageZoom('myimage', 'myresult');">
    <img id="myimage" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/263237/36633897-d3237f2e-19ad-11e8-960a-daaf5ca3088a.png"
     width="300" height="240">
    <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
} 

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: One more query .You have use a method imageZoom which will be invoked on mouseenter event. What will this method do ?

Comment: Agree that zooming will start but we need to put some logic in the method right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier) npm package. Click [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-img-magnifier) to see the working example on this Angular Image Zoom Package. It is easy to implement and provide full customization.

```
<ng-img-magnifier [thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'
    [imgWidth]='imgWidth' [imgHeight]='imgheight'
    [top]='top' [right]='right'
    [lensWidth]='lensewidth' [lensHeight]='lensheight'
    [resultWidth]='resultWidth' [resultHeight]='resultheight'>
</ng-img-magnifier>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngx-image-zoom` library for image zooming, so install it like this:

```
$ npm install ngx-image-zoom --save
```

After installation is completed, decorate your Angular app template, component and module like this:

**app.component.html:**

```
<lib-ngx-image-zoom
    [thumbImage]=myThumbnail
    [fullImage]=myFullresImage>
</lib-ngx-image-zoom>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myThumbnail="Thumb image path goes here";
  myFullresImage="Fullers image path goes here";
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 
// Import the library
import { NgxImageZoomModule } from 'ngx-image-zoom';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxImageZoomModule // <-- Add this line
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```